# Kotlin 'it' syntax in the context of Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, kotlin

Can someone explain to me how the Kotlin 'it' syntax in this snippet of code works? This code is very hard to read, someone sent it to me to fix my problem and it works like magic for multiple consecutive requests. I have used Volley before but this code is very confusing. I believe Kotlin is easier to read than Java but this particular code is very hard to understand.

```
val responses = mutableListOf<JSONObject>()
val myAPIUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins="
val myAPIKey = "REMOVED"
val transportMode = listOf("&mode=driving", "&mode=walking", "&mode=bicycling",
            "&mode=transit&transit_mode=bus", "mode=transit&transit_mode=subway", "mode=transit&transit_mode=train")

val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

transportMode.map { "$myAPIUrl$locationCoordinatesLat,$locationCoordinatesLong&destinations=$locationInput$it&key=$myAPIKey" }
            .map {
                JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, it, null, Response.Listener {
                    responses.add(it)
                }, Response.ErrorListener {
                   //nothing
                })
            }.forEach { queue.add(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, each entry in the `transportMode` list is mapped to the same String `"$myAPIUrl$locationCoordinatesLat,$locationCoordinatesLong&destinations=$locationInput$it&key=$myAPIKey"`, basically throwing away the transport mode. Let's call it `A`.

Then, the resulting list of these Strings is mapped to a `JsonObjectRequest`s, where the URL is set to `it`, which is one of the Strings `A` of your list. Each `JsonObjectRequest` also has a success callback and an error callback. The former receives the resulting `JSONObject` as the implicit `it` parameter, so `responses.add(it)` adds the `JSONObject` to the list of responses.

The last `it` can be found in the lambda function passed to `forEach`. It's one of the `JsonObjectRequest` objects created in the last `map`-step. The lambda adds it to the Volley request queue.

To make things clearer, I've augmented your code with some hints:

```
transportMode.map { mode -> "$myAPIUrl$locationCoordinatesLat,$locationCoordinatesLong&destinations=$locationInput$it&key=$myAPIKey" }
        .map { url ->
            JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener { responseJsonObject ->
                responses.add(responseJsonObject)
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
               //nothing
            })
        }.forEach { request -> queue.add(request) }
```

Comment: I think your explanation is very clear. What I want to know more about, is how the sequence of the code is executed? Such as why the `forEach` is placed at the end of the snippet instead of at the beginning.

Comment: @JAdonaiDagdag That's out of scope for this StackOverflow post, but if you're using IntelliJ, hold CTRL and click a function name like `forEach`. IntelliJ will show you its code, which might be of help. If that doesn't help, perhaps try asking this in a seperate question :)

Answer (score 2):

`it` is an [implicit name](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) of a single parameter used within a function literal.

For example, in your code, `transportMode` is a `Array<String>`, when you call:

```
transportMode.map {
    "..."
}
```

Here you are passing a function which has a `String` as the only parameter and a `String` as the return value. So, `it` inside the curly braces here represents a `String`.

If you think `it` is not readable for you. You can explicitly name the parameter:

```
transportMode.map {
    tag ->
    "$myAPIUrl$locationCoordinatesLat,$locationCoordinatesLong&destinations=$locationInput$tag&key=$myAPIKey"
}
```

Comment: This is correct. I'd like to add that in order to get a quick understanding where the value comes from, you can place your cursor on the `it`, press Alt+Enter and choose "Replace 'it' with explicit parameter", that way you can give it a more obvious name and see exactly from lambda the parameter comes from.

Answer (score 1):

`it` is the implicit name of a single parameter to the nearest lambda.

```
list.forEach { queue.add(it) } // it represents current item
list.forEach { item -> queue.add(item) } // Rename it if you like
// first it from nestList, second from the first it
nestList.forEach { it.forEach { queue.add(it) } }
```

Read more at [official document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `it` variable is the [implicit name of a single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) in Higher-Order Functions and Lambdas.

With the first `map()` you create the url with the mode you append to the end with `"...$it&key=$myAPIKey""`. Here `it` is something like `"&mode=driving"`.

With the second `map()` you create the requests for the urls (the `it` used as parameter) and with `responses.add(it)` you add the response given to you in the listener to the list of responses.

With the `forEach()` you then iterate over all requests and to enqueue these.